# Yii2 Editable Image

Tags: php, css, image, widget, yii2

Is it possible to make an image editable? I have an invoice template and I make store details (store logo, name, address, email, etc.) of that invoice editable. Everything's working fine except that I don't know how to make the store logo editable.

Here's how I display the store logo:

```
<img src="<?php echo $model->storeLogo; ?>" width="150"><br><br>
```

Now, I tried Kartik's Editable widget with `INPUT_FILEINPUT` but it only displays the image path:

```
<?php 
    echo Editable::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'name'=> 'storeLogo', 
        'value' => $model->storeLogo,
        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_FILEINPUT,
        'header' => 'Logo',
        'size'=>'md',
        'options' => ['class'=>'form-control']
    ]);
?>
```

Example output of the widget above is:

> logo/acct.jpg

How do I let the image itself to be editable? Or are there any other ways to edit the image?
Your thoughts would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'editable', do you mean that you want to be able to change the image, or that you want to be able to crop, resize or change the actual uploaded image?

Comment: I want to change the image then implement the crop/resize later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I put this in my view:

```
<div class="fileUpload kv-editable-value kv-editable-link">
    <span><img class="pull-left" src="<?php echo $model->storeLogo; ?>" width="150" height="150" id="output"></span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="upload"/>
</div>
```

Then I added a javascript:

```
<script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

And style:

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 150px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

I searched this solution over stackoverflow as well but I already don't have the link. Here's how it looks now:

[image]

So when I click on the image, a window will appear for me to select another image. Btw, all these are just frontend so I don't need to reupload an image again and save it to my database.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you use [Kartik's file input](http://webtips.krajee.com/upload-file-yii-2-using-fileinput-widget/) widget? This will easily allow you upload a new image to replace the one you have.

As for editing the image, this will need to be done at the front end, for which you will need a javascript or jquery library, connected to Yii2's 'Imagine' library. There are plenty out there, you just need to find the one that's right for what you want to edit.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. However, I think I have solved this problem. I just posted my answer.